# How to set or update state of Array in grand child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set state of array from grand child component which is located in parent component.

I tried to use `setNumberOfVar([...varsLines]);` this method but it's not updating the state immediately.it updates but one step back.

My Code

```
  const removeVar = (e, val) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var varsLines = numberOfVar;
    varsLines = numberOfVar.filter((item) => {
      return item.postion != val;
    });
    varsLines = varsLines.map((item) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        postion: item.postion > val ? item.postion - 1 : item.postion,
      };
    });
    console.log(varsLines);
    setNumberOfVar([...varsLines]); // <== this line is not updating the state immediately;
    console.log(numberOfVar);
  };
```

Comment: react do not do updation immediately. It do a batch updation, that is why updations are not reflected immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setNumberOfVar() is an async operation and will not update state immediately.

If you want to get something like a callback when the state is updated, you can use the useEffect hook that runs on state update.

```
import {useEffect } from 'react';

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(numberOfVar);
  },[numberOfVar]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but now when I delete something it only deletes the last element from the array

Comment: and what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

try to do something like this

```
setNumberOfVar(prevState=>prevState.filter().map())
```

use your own conditions in filter and map and see if it's working or not.

Comment: Thanks for Fast replay but still same problem